# How can I fake a "Change" on an input in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using a 3rd party app to upload an image.  The way Image uploads are currently handled is with a button which is clicked, an image is chosen, and the file is uploaded.  I am trying to add a "drag to upload" feature on our page.  I have gotten it to work, but ONLY after an image has been uploaded the standard way.  Is there a way to "fake" an image upload so that the third party app believes I have uploaded an image before I drag my image over?  Something like the .click() method but for .change() on an input?  Or even a way to upload a blank image automatically the standard way before my drag upload is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trigger the event using jquery:

```
var yourMethod = function(){
    $( "#foo" ).trigger( "change" );
}
```

Comment: I believe this is only for doing something AFTER the file is changed no?  I am looking for a way to change the file.